# steps to create a second heroku app from the same computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to create a completely separate app from my computer. Up to this point, I only have on folder that I worked off of which I used git to push my updates to heroku.

How do I go about creating a completely separate heroku app while at the same allowing me to revert back and forth between the two apps?

I want to keep the first app as it is but I want to start developing a second app as a trial with the flexibility to be able to go back and work on the first app and vice versa.

Comment: Two different versions of the same app (like staging and production environments), or two totally different apps?

Comment: two totally different apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err... I'm not sure if it's something I'm missing in your question, but this should be pretty straight-forward.

Create your new app

```
$ rails new yourapp
$ cd yourapp
```

Create a repository

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Create, deploy and open the app @ Heroku

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku open
```

**EDIT:** If what your looking for is a duplicated app on a new herokudomain, do as follows:

Duplicate you app folder locally and cd into the copy.

Delete the current remote (origin)

```
git remote rm origin
```

Add the new remote

```
git remote add origin <URL to second heroku app>
```

push to new domain

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I'm looking to create a completely new and separate app (not a duplicate). After I create a new app, how can I switch back into my previous git? (of the first app)

Comment: Ok, I see. Git repos are connected to the app-folder of the specific app locally. If you want to work on two different repos at the same time, without them interconnecting in any way, just open two terminal/consoles and cd to the different apps in one window each. Then start working on your new app and hop in to the old one at ease. Let's say the path for your apps is documents/rails/app1 and documents/rails/app2. These two paths have separate git repos, and they are not interfering with each other. If you're not familiar with the terminology here, keep asking, we'll figure it out ;)

Comment: I followed the steps above, and it looks like it overwrote my first app on heroku. How can I make it go to a new heroku app URL?

Comment: How can I make it go to http://floating-dusk-xxxx.herokuapp.com/ (the newly created), instead of the code getting pushed to http://boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com (my original app). I'm uploading from a different app folder but it still got pushed to the first app's heroku

Comment: Well, thats wierd... Are you uploading with the commands I mentioned above, while being CD'd into the correct directory? Did you try deleting the current remote (as mentioned) and adding a new one? That should work.

Comment: Also make sure you're following [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) steps when creating a new app at Heroku.

Comment: I tried `git remote rm origin` but I got this error - `could not remove config section 'remote.origin'`. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: This error means that the remote you requested to delete doesn't exist. Make sure there is an existing remote, if not, create a new right away. Also make sure you've got the correct name of the remote you want to get rid of. Do `git remote -v` to see the existing remotes. When you've found the name of your remote, do `git remote rm yourname`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your apps are in entirely separate directories (one shouldn't be a subdirectory of the other).  Something like this is typical:

```
workspace
  |
  |----- my_app_1
  |         |
  |         |---- .git
  |         |       |
  |         |       |---- config
  |         |       |---- ...
  |         |      
  |         |----- app
  |         |----- Gemfile
  |         |----- ...
  |
  |----- my_app_2
  |         |
  |         |---- .git
  |         |       |
  |         |       |---- config
  |         |       |---- ...
  |         |      
  |         |----- app
  |         |----- Gemfile
  |         |----- ...
  |
  |----- ...
```

So you might have a `workspace` directory, which contains several Rails application directories `my_app_1`, `my_app_2`, etc.  And each of those directories are structures like a typical Rails-application-with-git-version-control project.

- To create a new rails app, `cd` into your `workspace` directory, and enter the command `rails new my_app_x`.
- To initialize it as a git repository, `cd` into the newly created
  `my_app_x` directory and enter the command `git init` (followed by a
  `git add .; git commit -m "initial commit"`).

Finally, you need to make sure that the `.git/config` files are set up correctly for each project.  You probably want your two apps `.git/config` files to look something like the following:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:floating-dusk-xxxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

And the other one like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = false
[remote "heroku"]
    url = git@heroku.com:boiling-bastion-xxxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

It's okay if your config files look a little different, and have some extra sections in them, the key part is the `url` under the `[remote "heroku"]` section.

Then, you can push these two different apps to two different Heroku repositories (which then lets you navigate to these two apps at their seperate, respective `blah-blah-xxxx.herokuapp.com` URLs.  In order to push an app to Heroku, make sure you've `cd`'d into the correct directory and then enter the command `git push heroku master`.  This may not work right away in case the state you've left those Heroku remote repositories in is currently messed up, so please comment with any errors you run into.